# Using switchee to detect pagination

Tags: pagination, switchee, zoo-triggers

I'm using Switchee to detect pagination.

Switchee is working fine for: /new/PX/

I also use Zoo Triggers for categories and archives and have the following pagination URL's too:

- /news/category/abc/PX (segment 4)
- /news/archive/yyyy/mm/PX (segment
  5)

It doesn't look like I can pass multiple values to the *variable* parameter so is it best to call Switchee multiple times in the template or is there a better approach?

```
{exp:switchee variable="{triggers:segment_2}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="#^P(\d+)$#"}
    // Do something
    {/case}

    {case value="''" default="Yes"}
    // Do something
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}

{exp:switchee variable="{triggers:segment_4}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="#^P(\d+)$#"}
    // Do something
    {/case}

    {case value="''" default="Yes"}
    // Do something
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}

{exp:switchee variable="{triggers:segment_5}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="#^P(\d+)$#"}
    // Do something
    {/case}

    {case value="''" default="Yes"}
    // Do something
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: as far as i know you can nest switchee too. that would help, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried Bjorn's last segment plugin to get the absolute last segment and that worked. Weird...

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bjorn-last-segment

Switchee tag:

`{exp:switchee variable="{exp:last_segment ignore_pagination='no'}" parse="inward"}`

Answer (score 0):

`{triggers:last_segment}` ?

And here's a useless sentence to make this answer long enough to post...

Comment: I tried last segment but this was always returning /news/ and never PX.

Comment: For example `{triggers:last_segment}` for http://domain.com/news/archive/2013/12/P5 returns 12.